# Translation table - как перевести?

Tags: linux

Подскажите более-менее адекватный (литературный) перевод. 
Статья о памяти в Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translation table (sinyagin_computer)

> адресная таблица, таблица страниц.
>         Программная или аппаратная структура
>          данных, используемая для преобразования 
>         виртуальных адресов в физические.

translation table (MultiTran GDr)

> 1. косм. координатный столик
> 2. тех. адресная таблица (для перевода
>        виртуальных адресов в физические)
> 3. матем. кодовая таблица
> 4. выч. таблица переадресации, таблица
>        перевода (напр. виртуальных адресов
>        в физические), таблица
>        преобразования, таблица страниц,
>        трансляционная таблица, адресная
>        таблица
> 5. безоп. таблица преобразований

поставьте GoldenDict (оболочка для словарей) и загрузите с торрентов словари, тогда будет вам счастье :)

Comment: Я lingvo.ua обычно пользуюсь, но мне перевод "таблица переводов" совсем не понравился :-) Спасибо.

Comment: @setevoy2 мне тоже, потому добавил инфу из другого словаря.

Comment: Помимо lingvo, у меня ещё +100500 словарей, и всё в одной программе на любой ОС.